# can javascript in visual studio be aware of debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2019 for an external javascript library to be aware of VS's `Debug` or `Release` mode?  I have an annoying issue where on my desktop the path to a javascript library is:

```
$.getJSON(
    "/MyController/MyMethod"
)...
```

but in Release or when Published to test or prod the path is:

```
$.getJSON(
    "/MyApp/MyController/MyMethod"
)...
```

It would be nice to be able to programmatically swap between the two because I forget every singe time.

Comment: You might be able to get away with it if you use the variables from within the config/tasks json file. [reference to ms docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference)

Comment: I have a workaround that I don't think qualifies as an "answer". I set a cookie in each API method that sets the runtime debug state. I check that in the js file and that's working so far. Cheers